# Is there a better way in R to split a file with multiple sections

Tags: r, csv, parsing

I am reading in a CSV file into R that contains multiple sections, the sections contain different headers, number of rows and columns. Example table below, I need to separate them into different data frames so I can process them based on the section type.

[image]

The number of sections can change and so far I have only figured out how to hard code them and use grep to split the different sections into different data frames.

The sections are all in the same format **==XY==** where X is a letter and Y is a number

Is there a better way to split the data frame into a different data frame for each section no matter how many sections there are?

```
z1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("==C5===", "H1", "1", "3", "8", "==E5===", 
                            "H1", "10", "2", "==G6===", "H1", "5", "==H4===", "H1", "1", 
                            "==H6===", "H1", "10"), V2 = c("", "H2", "9", "8", "1", "", "H2", 
                                                           "4", "2", "", "", "", "", "H2", "8", "", "", ""), V3 = c("", 
                                                                                                                    "H3", "2", "5", "6", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                                                                                                    "", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
DF1 <- z1[grep("==C5", z1$V1):grep("==E5", z1$V1),]
DF2 <- z1[grep("==E5", z1$V1):grep("==G6", z1$V1),]
DF3 <- z1[grep("==G6", z1$V1):grep("==H4", z1$V1),]
DF4 <- z1[grep("==H4", z1$V1):grep("==H6", z1$V1),]
DF5 <- z1[grep("==H6", z1$V1):nrow(z1),]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are starting out with a csv, here is a way to read in each specific set of rows.

```
write.table(z1, "tmp.csv", na ="", row.names = FALSE, 
            col.names = FALSE, sep = ",")

tmp <- readLines("tmp.csv")

# start of each 'file'
sof <- grep("==", tmp)

# the actual start is one past that
real_start <- sof + 1

# figure out the end of each unique df
real_end <- c(sof[-1] - 1, length(tmp))

# the number of rows to read in
to_read <- real_end - real_start

# a list to store your data.frames
my_dfs <- vector("list", length = length(real_start))
for(i in 1:length(my_dfs)){
  # suppressing warnings, as there are a lot 
  #  that come up when a column header is not
  #  in a specific data.frame
  my_dfs[[i]] <- suppressWarnings(
    data.table::fread("tmp.csv",
                      skip = sof[i],
                      nrows = to_read[i],
                      fill = FALSE,
                      check.names = FALSE,
                      data.table = FALSE,
                      select = c("H1", "H2", "H3")
    )
  )
}
```

The output of this is:

```
[[1]]
  H1 H2 H3
1  1  9  2
2  3  8  5
3  8  1  6

[[2]]
  H1 H2
1 10  4
2  2  2

[[3]]
  H1
1  5

[[4]]
  H1 H2
1  1  8

[[5]]
  H1
1 10
```

If you do not know the column headers you could use `read.csv` instead, but you end up with some `NA` columns.

```
my_dfs2 <- vector("list", length = length(real_start))
for(i in 1:length(my_dfs2)){
  # suppressing warnings, as there are a lot 
  #  that come up when a column header is not
  #  in a specific data.frame
  my_dfs2[[i]] <- 
             read.csv("tmp.csv",
                      skip = sof[i],
                      nrows = to_read[i],
                      fill = FALSE
             )
}
```

The output from this is:

```
[[1]]
  H1 H2 H3
1  1  9  2
2  3  8  5
3  8  1  6

[[2]]
  H1 H2  X
1 10  4 NA
2  2  2 NA

[[3]]
  H1  X X.1
1  5 NA  NA

[[4]]
  H1 H2  X
1  1  8 NA

[[5]]
  H1  X X.1
1 10 NA  NA
```

You could then remove the NA columns as the next processing step.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
lapply(split(z1, cumsum(grepl("=", z1$V1))), tail, -1)

$`1`
  V1 V2 V3
2 H1 H2 H3
3  1  9  2
4  3  8  5
5  8  1  6

$`2`
  V1 V2 V3
7 H1 H2   
8 10  4   
9  2  2   

$`3`
   V1 V2 V3
11 H1      
12  5      

$`4`
   V1 V2 V3
14 H1 H2   
15  1  8   

$`5`
   V1 V2 V3
17 H1      
18 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Below we assume that what you really want is to have the `H1`, `H2`, ... as the column names of each data.frame created.

Paste the columns together giving `p`, remove the == elements giving `p2`, form a grouping variable `g` and split `p2` on g using `read.table` to read in each component.  No packages are used.

```
p <- do.call(paste, z1)
p2 <- p[!grepl("^==", p)]
g <- cumsum(grepl("^\\D", p2))
L <- lapply(split(p2, g), function(x) read.table(text = x, header = TRUE))
L
```

giving this list of data frames:

```
$`1`
  H1 H2 H3
1  1  9  2
2  3  8  5
3  8  1  6

$`2`
  H1 H2
1 10  4
2  2  2

...etc...
```

Below we discuss some additional things we can optionally do with `L`.

### Loose data frames

Although not really recommended if you really want to create loose data frames hanging out in your global environment you could do this:

```
names(L) <- paste0("DF", names(L))
list2env(L, .GlobalEnv)
```

### Using title

If the title on the == lines has meaning we could use them instead of 1, 2, 3, ... like this:

```
names(L) <- trimws(gsub("=", "", grep("^==", p, value = TRUE)))
L
```

giving:

```
$C5
  H1 H2 H3
1  1  9  2
2  3  8  5
3  8  1  6

$E5
  H1 H2
1 10  4
2  2  2

...etc...
```

### Creating a data frame from the list

We could use `rbindlist` in data.table to create a data frame/data.table from `L` like this:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(L, fill = TRUE, id = "id")
```

giving the following where `id` identifies the component number.

```
   id H1 H2 H3
1:  1  1  9  2
2:  1  3  8  5
3:  1  8  1  6
4:  2 10  4 NA
5:  2  2  2 NA
6:  3  5 NA NA
7:  4  1  8 NA
8:  5 10 NA NA
```

or this if you had set the titles on the == lines as the names:

```
     id H1 H2 H3
1: C5    1  9  2
2: C5    3  8  5
3: C5    8  1  6
4: E5   10  4 NA
5: E5    2  2 NA
6: G6    5 NA NA
7: H4    1  8 NA
8: H6   10 NA NA
```